# Combine strings in a certain order

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

**Sample table**

| NUMBER | DEAL_NUMBER | NAME1 | NAME2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | T01 | TOM | JERRY |
| 2 | T02 | LEBRON | STEVEN |

Would like **output** as below:

| NUMBER | DEAL_NUMBER | NAME1 | NAME2 | Name_COM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | T01 | TOM | JERRY | LEBRON TOM STEVEN JERRY |
| 2 | T02 | LEBRON | STEVEN | LEBRON TOM STEVEN JERRY |

By using string_agg function can solve with it, but it is not convenient enough.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION EXCHANGE_PLACE(STR STRING)
RETURNS STRING
AS

((
          SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(array_reverse(ARRAY_LIST),' ') FROM (SELECT SPLIT(STR,' ')ARRAY_LIST)
));

WITH TBL_D_CUSTOMER AS
(
 SELECT "1" AS NUMBER,"T01" AS DEAL_NUMBER,"TOM" AS NAME1, "JERRY" AS NAME2 UNION ALL 
 SELECT "2","T01","LEBRON","STEVEN"
)


SELECT 
       *,
EXCHANGE_PLACE(STRING_AGG(NAME1,' ')OVER(PARTITION BY DEAL_NUMBER)) || ' ' || EXCHANGE_PLACE(STRING_AGG(NAME2,' ')OVER(PARTITION BY DEAL_NUMBER)) AS NAME_COM
FROM TBL_D_CUSTOMER
```

Is there any approach can do it better?

Comment: Please clarify 1) the logic behind `Name_COM` - how you want it to be assembled 2) why `string_agg` is not convenient enough for you - please clarify so we can help you further :o)

Comment: 1) here show the sample and targeted output after edited, it might show the logic of assembled
2)here create extra temp function to solve or use subqueries, can it possible to fulfill the same result with less query?

Answer (score 2):

Consider below approach

```
select *, array_to_string(
  array_reverse(array_agg(NAME1) over win) || array_reverse(array_agg(NAME2) over win)
  , ' ') as Name_COM
from TBL_D_CUSTOMER 
window win as (partition by DEAL_NUMBER)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: It works! thanks Berlyant! here find out the thinking after compare the method.